# Generative Grammar

Tags: syntax

I would need to do a contrastive study on how "would" is dealt with in Generative Grammar and that of Leech and Svartvik (A communicative grammar of English).

Has anyone worked on such a thing before?

I would appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Hi, Mike! Your question is too broad as it is. According to our standards, questions like this should be closed, but it seems to me that there is something quite interesting and informative here. So, please, try to narrow it down to a few specific points you want/need to know.

Comment: @Mike What's the point? I'm guessing that Leech and Svartvik is going to be massively inadaquete as a linguistic analysis (as most communicative grammars are). People have written entire PhD dissertations on English modal auxiliaries in generative grammar. It's hardly a fair comparison.

Comment: @Mike I'll probably get shouted at for using the C-word, but you might want to take a look at Chomsky's 61 article 'some methodological remarks on generative grammar' (here: http://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=UDvxLxFsci4C&oi=fnd&pg=PA31&dq=some+metholodical+remarks+on+generative+grammar&ots=BaEf0uUz4j&sig=FBCXEa8WSRk2AZ8ljPSM5j6D2y4#v=onepage&q&f=false) which has some remarks on the diff between generative grammar and traditional grammars.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "generative grammar"? What Chomsky called "generative grammar" in 1961 is very very far removed from what people might call "generative grammar" nowadays. For another possibility, check McCawley 1998 _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_, which is a generative grammar of English, though not a very Chomskyan one.